# Moving Database that uses filestream

Tags: sql-server-2008, sqlfilestream

I have enabled filestream, and I create a database in SQL server management studio with a filegroup/filestream.

I want to use the resulting database in visual studio, so I copy over the 2 files (mdf & ldf) and the filestream folder to App_Data.

I get the following error message in VS server explorer:

**FILESTREAM feature is disabled.

A file activation error occurred. The physical file name 'C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\FOO\App_Data\fooFilestream' may be incorrect. Diagnose and correct additional errors, and retry the operation.

Could not open new database 'C:\USERS\USER\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\FOO\APP_DATA\FOO.MDF'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted.

An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\FOO\App_Data\foo.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.**

Any suggestions? This process works fine with databases that don't use a filestream.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here is the issue: MS Visual Studio cannot connect to a database as a file when that database makes use of the filestream feature.

So what I did was connect to the database with SQL Server Management Studio, and then connect to it in VisualStudio.